# Is there an easy way to mask passwords in RStudio using Window's internal user environment variables?

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio

I tried doing some research but can't seem to find anything about using Window's User Environment Variables to some form of get request in RStudio. I know that this can be done in Python quite easily. I tried the below but it gives me a blank string as the output.

```
library(sys)
Password <- Sys.getenv("<input windows user variable>")
Password
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to imput or prompt the password nor have it stord in the script itself.

Comment: If you intend to prompt the user for a password, and you appear to be using the RStudio IDE, then `rstudioapi::askForSecret` or `rstudioapi::askForPassword` might work. If you want something else, look into the [`keyring`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keyring/index.html) package.

Comment: Otherwise, the topic of "securely" (in air-quotes) asking somebody to type in a password in a language often uses attempts to turn off "echo". This is possible in a TTY, but R does not support that. Because of that, you need to get "secrets" through some other interface or mechanism. You might try https://magesblog.com/post/2014-07-15-simple-user-interface-in-r-to-get-login/, or perhaps the `getPass` package. If in shiny, consider `passwordInput`. For a more sustained effort, I suggest `keyring` or perhaps `config` are good ways to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one can be configured using the `rstudioapi` package. No need for the `sys` package.

Try like this:

```
library(rstudioapi)
username <- showPrompt(title="Username", message="Enter your username:", default="")
password <- askForPassword(prompt="Enter your password:")
```

[image]
[image]